# How to synchronize sounds | PUN2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I want to implement the player to make a sound in an online shooter, but the sound is not synchronized.
Specifically, the attachment of AudioClip cannot be synchronized.

I tried with this code:

```
void Start()
{
    photonView.RPC(nameof(MakeSound), RpcTarget.All);
}

[SerializeField]
AudioSource AudioSource;
[SerializeField]
AudioClip clip;

[PunRPC]
void MakeSound()
{
    AudioSource.clip = clip;
    AudioSource.Play();
    Debug.Log("Played");
}
```

However, in this case, "Played" is executed without clip attached to AudioClip of AudioSource. No sound.

What should I do? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Just a thought, but are you sure `AudioSource.clip` is what you should be setting the clip to and not `AudioSource.AudioClip`? I don't know Unity very well, but since you mention `AudioClip` as being a property of the source it makes me think you're assigning it wrong.

Comment: AudioSource.clip is the same type as AudioClip. Although the name is duplicated, AudioClip changes every time, so I designed this way.

Comment: Well in that case, unless you have `clip` being set somewhere else, I would expect that your code is setting `AudioSource.clip` to `null`.

Comment: sorry. The clip was set with Unity's Inspecter. The code was bad. I will fix it.

Comment: Is `clip` referenced on all clients?